# What does $shipping_modules = new shipping($shipping); mean?

Tags: php, oop

What does the following code mean?

```
$shipping_modules = new shipping($shipping);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

...

```
$shipping_modules = new shipping($shipping);
```

The new instance of class `shipping` is assigned to variable `$shipping_modules` there by allowing you to access class methods/properties. Finally, `$shipping` variable is passed to the constructor of `shipping` class.

```
$shipping_modules = new shipping($shipping);
        1            2      3        4
```

**where:**

1. assigns new instance of `shipping` class to `$shipping_modules` variable
2. `new` operator to create instance of the class
3. The class name eg `shipping`
4. The variable `$shipping` passed to constructor of the class.

**[See PHP OOP Tutorial](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Object-Oriented-Programming-with-PHP.html)**

Answer (score 3):

It means:

1. Create a new shipping object
2. In doing so, pass the $shipping variable to the __construct function of the shipping object
3. Then assign this new object to the $shipping_modules variable